# Flutter - ListView's items' row tile not updating on state build

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-state

The list doesn't update after an item removed. It only removes the last row. I simplified the code as much as possible since I can't see anything wrong elsewhere. Either this is weird or I was missing something.

```
class ListState extends State<ListWidget>{

  ...

  List<Item> list = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print([for(Item item in list) item.name]); //The list is updated so nothing wrong here
    List<Tile> children = [];
    for(Item item in list) children.add(Tile(item) .. parent = this);
    return ListView(children : children, controller : controller);
  }

  void remove(Item item) => setState((){
    list.remove(item);
  });

  ...
}

class Tile extends StatefulWidget{

  Item item;
  ListState parent;

  Tile(this.item);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => TileState() .. item = item;
}

class TileState extends State<Tile>{

  Item item;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ListTile(
      key: ValueKey(item.name),
      title: Text(item.name),
      onTap: () => widget.parent.remove(item),
    );
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling  remove method ?

Comment: @HardikMehta from the tile. but the list is updated so i don't think that's where the issue came from

Comment: forgot to mention. i followed this example https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/flutter+listview+builder+remove+item

Comment: you `setState` the list, but not the `children` list.  try to assign list on children directly,

Comment: Can you include full widget here

Comment: or try to move this `List<Tile> children = [];`  to the top. ( outside of `build` method)

Comment: @pmatatias sorry i don't get it. which children list you mean?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh nothing special with it

class ListWidget extends StatefulWidget{

  ListWidget({Key? key}) : super(key : key);

  \\@override
  State<ListWidget> createState() => ListState();
}

Comment: @stackunderflow the `ListView` children.
i think , your `List<Item> list = [];` is already updated. but the `Listview` still showing old vesion of this `List<Tile> children = [];`

Comment: @pmatatias exactly that's my problem

Comment: try to move the `List<Tile> children = [];` outside of `build` method.

Comment: @pmatatias same. the example i followed use listview.builder also doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs from callback, you can direclty using VoidCallBack

Changes on `Tile`

```dart
class Tile extends StatefulWidget {
  final _HomeItem item;
  final Function delete;

  Tile(this.item, this.delete);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TileState();
}

class _TileState extends State<Tile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text("${widget.item.title}"),
      subtitle: Text("${widget.item.index}"),
      onTap: () => widget.delete(),
    );
  }
}
```

And use case

```dart
return Tile(items[index], () {
  items.remove(items[index]);
  setState(() {});
});
```

Full Snippet

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title = "F";

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List<_HomeItem> items = List.generate(
    5,
    (i) => _HomeItem(
      i,
      'Tile n°$i',
    ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _buildList(context),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Tile(items[index], () {
          items.remove(items[index]);
          setState(() {});
        });
      },
      itemCount: items.length,
    );
  }
}

class Tile extends StatefulWidget {
  final _HomeItem item;
  final Function delete;

  Tile(this.item, this.delete);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TileState();
}

class _TileState extends State<Tile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text("${widget.item.title}"),
      subtitle: Text("${widget.item.index}"),
      onTap: () => widget.delete(),
    );
  }
}

class _HomeItem {
  const _HomeItem(
    this.index,
    this.title,
  );

  final int index;
  final String title;
}
```

Comment: why it's working?. can you please explain why do i need to move all fields from state to widget?

Comment: I move the fields because it not necessary to create state variables while we already have widget value. Also `Tile` widget is totally depended on parent widget

Comment: i thought it's all new tiles when listview.build is called. so that means it's been reused that's why the tiles' state is not updated. right?

Comment: Well you did reinitialize them, but doing operation inside build, reinitialize the value on every build.

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/lodash_flutter

```
List singleList = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    List list = [
      {'id': 1},
      {
        'id': 2,
      },
      {'id': 3}
    ];

    List singleChildren = [];

    for (var i in singleList) {
      singleChildren.add(i);
    }
    singleChildren.remove(1);
    print(singleChildren); //[2, 3]

    ///Multidimension array

    List multiChildren = [];
    for (var i in list) {
      multiChildren.add({'id': i['id']});
    }

    multiChildren.removeWhere((item) => item['id'] == 2);
    print(multiChildren);

    /// [{id: 2}, {id: 3}]
```